# How can I integrate react-chartjs-2 with chartjs-plugin-datasource to use a datasource at an s3 url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first post to stackoverflow and I would really appreciate any help if it could be given!

**Background**

I am a newbie web developer but have experience developing python applications for data pipelines and ML.

I have created an AWS amplify application using react and am trying to create a dashboard within it to show the results of some processed data. The datafile I am trying to retrieve is a .csv file.

I have chosen to use chartjs-2 for visualisation and so am using the [react-chartjs-2](https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2) wrapper, to enable me to load in csv data from a url I am using the [chartjs-plugin-datasource](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-datasource/) plugin.

**Dashboard component code**

Below is my current code for the dashboard component.

```js
import React from "react";
import Amplify, { Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import awsmobile from "./aws-exports";
import { Doughnut, Chart } from "react-chartjs-2";
import ChartDataSource from "chartjs-plugin-datasource";
// TODO create a dashboard app with a chartjs set of views and a pivot table component
// TODO create a storage.get method that goes and retrieves the file
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);
Storage.configure({ level: "private" });
Chart.plugins.register(ChartDataSource);

export default function Dashboard() {
  const getFileURL = async e => {
    Storage.get("test.csv", { level: "private" })
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  const fileURL = getFileURL();

  return (
    <Doughnut
      data={{url : fileURL}}
      options={{
        datasource: {
          url: fileURL,
          rowMapping: "index",
          datasetLabels: "some cell range",
          indexLabels: "some cell range",
          data: "the data to be displayed as a cell range"
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

**Debugging**

The getFileURL method works as expected, I have reviewed the results in the developer options in chrome.

I get two errors in the developer console:

1. Uncaught Error: "undefined" is not a data source type.

I believe the issue here is that it is not recognising the url datasource and downloading the object. I think this could either because the plugin is not being enabled correctly or that it is simply reading the url rather than pulling the file.

2. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined.

Frankly I have no idea what this means in this context.

How do I resolve these issues so that I can get my csv file into my doughnut chart?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `ChartDataSource` as a plugins option.

```
     <Doughnut
      data={{ url: fileURL }}
      plugins={[ChartDataSource]}
      options={{
        plugins: {
          datasource: {
            type: 'csv',
            url: fileURL,
            rowMapping: 'index',
            datasetLabels: "some cell range",
            indexLabels: "some cell range",
          }
        }
      }}
    />
```